# What is the best way to work with nested svn working copies in a working copy from the same subversion repository?

Tags: php, svn

My team maintains a single multi-project subversion repository of our PHP source code.
We have a simple deployment strategy where libraries used by applications are stored in it's directory structure. This makes deployment possible by using either a tarball or by checking the code out of subversion.
This all works well but in an admin role in the past I've told svn users not to create nested working copies or rearrange the code tree especially in a working copy that is leading the head of the trunk branch.

We have a more complicated repository but the important parts are this:

```
trunk/app4/libs/libB
trunk/lib1
```

LibB is included to illustrate that some libs are stored with the apps where they are deployed but actively developed libs shared across applications are stored at the level we consider a project in the repository.If we were to follow the same structure in the working copy that we have in the repository the file tree would look like this:

```
parent_dir/
   app4/libs/libB
   lib1/
```

but for our delpoyment we need to structure the code tree like this:

```
app4/
   libs/
     lib1
     libB
```

I've used following steps to set this up.
    # svn co  svn://svn.example.com/trunk/app4 ./
    # cd app4/libs
    # svn co ssvn://svn.example.com/trunk/lib1

The result is that the lib1 directory is not included in the in the app1 part of the working copy making the status of app1 unclean, but is the root of it's own working copy. This makes  the svn status of the app1 working copy unclean because the directory lib1 is a new file in the app4 working copy.

# svn status

returns

```
? lib1
```

Is it a good idea to clear this by adding Could i svn add the lib1 directory from app1/libs?  One might hope that this will add p1/libs/lib1 directory to the svn info for app1 without any change to app1/libs/lib1/.svn/  but I think that is very unlikely. (TODO: Test this in an example)

Is it best to just personally ignore that status or maybe add libs/lib1 to ignore to get a clean status? What are some other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution is to create 2 working copies like this.

```
app4_prj/
  app4/
      libs/
        lib1

lib1_prj
  app4/
     libs/
       lib1
```

In both:

```
# cd app4/libs 
# svn ignore lib1
```

Develop on lib1 and app4 in their respective projects. That way when each project is checked in the working copies have a clean status, lib1 is not duplicated in svn and you can more easily test and tinker with the lib and include changes from other team members while continuing to develop the app,

Answer (score 0):

You can't change mount-point of repo-nodes, using Working Copy only (regarding lib1). **New repository** (with externals) **must be** created and used

Comment: The working copy is working as it's set up. I am not advocated doing this but it's just fine. Also It's fine to have one repository and manage projects in various directories. This seems to be more of a comment than an answer.